# Correct way to determine dbus destination for a proxy

Tags: rust, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to figure out, what should be the correct way to determine what `destination` should be used with proxy when it's value is set to `(null destination)`?

I'm currently trying to receive Bluetooth signals of device data using [rust's DBus impelementation](https://docs.rs/dbus/latest/dbus/).

Signals I'm getting:

```
signal time=1641856074.929459 sender=:1.2 -> destination=(null destination) serial=152 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_<mac>; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.Device1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "ManufacturerData"
         variant             array [
               dict entry(
                  uint16 1177
                  variant                      array of bytes [
                        05 0f c0 1e ff cd 59 ff e4 ff e0 03 e4 4c 36 b0 31 46
                        c0 cb 4e 3d 3e 12
                     ]
               )
            ]
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

I happened to figure out by just testing out different things that the destination for the proxy is `org.bluez`.

Code I ended up using

```rust
    let conn = Connection::new_system()?;
    {
        let proxy = conn.with_proxy(
            "org.bluez",
            "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C0_CB_4E_3D_3E_12",
            Duration::from_millis(5000),
        );
    // --snip--
```

This works, but I'm not sure how I should've properly find this out or whether this is even the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.rs/dbus/latest/dbus/blocking/struct.Proxy.html) for `Proxy` it says the first field is the BusName:

```
    pub struct Proxy<'a, C> {
        pub destination: BusName<'a>,
        pub path: Path<'a>,
        pub timeout: Duration,
        pub connection: C,
    }
```

Looking at the details for that field is says that it is the D-Bus Service.

```
destination: BusName<'a> 
    Destination, i e what D-Bus service you’re communicating with
```

Looking at the [BlueZ documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt) for the `org.bluez.Device1` interface it says the service is `org.bluez`

```
> Service       org.bluez
> Interface     org.bluez.Device1 
> Object path   [variable prefix]/{hci0,hci1,...}/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX
```

So you are right and the links to the above documentation is how you would work it out.

Comment: Alright got you, but I think the BlueZ documentation isn't obvious about that the destination service is org.bluez. It just states the name of the service. Is that the case always, that the service is the destination?